# How to load OpenCV's PDB debug files for debugging OpenCV source codes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I compiled OpenCV and I have PDB file for both debug and release mode.
I can program and run OpenCV's APIs, but I can't debug into OpenCV's source files using F11.
I need to link to those pdb files. I did the followings, but still have the problems.

(1)Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols > Check Microsoft Symbols Server
(2)In the same dialog, at Cache symbols in this directory, I link to D:\OpenCV_Lib_2.4.6\Win64\bin\Debug, where pdb files are there.
(3)Set D:\OpenCV_Lib_2.4.6\Win64\bin\Debug and D:\OpenCV_Lib_2.4.6\Win64\bin\Release to Environment Path.
What else I still need to do to have debugging into OpenCV's sources.
I use Visual Studio 2010.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The first step, all library files must have their pdb files in the same folder where library files are located. Secondly, in the VC++ project setting Configuration properties -> C/C++ -> optimization -> Disable. If it is selected for maximize speed, will have problem. Finally, Configuration properties -> Linker -> Debugging -> Generate debug info -> YES. Then problem is solved.